# run code within 10 seconds

Tags: php

This is my php code. I want to run it within in 10 second if it run within in 10 second then print `$content`, otherwise print error message. Also, if `$content` is null then print error message and if not null, then print `$content`.

```
<?php
$content=file_get_contents("http://anyurl/test1.php");
if($content=="") {
  echo "there is error";
} else {
  echo $content;
}
?>
```

Comment: basically you want it to timeout after 10 seconds?

Comment: You don't need javascript for that.

Comment: If you are loading a remote URL you could use libcurl with a timeout.

Comment: i can use use remote url then what should be code for that

Answer (score 4):

Set a timeout in a context

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'timeout' => 10, // Number of seconds for timeout
        )
    )
);
$content = file_get_contents("http://anyurl/test1.php", false, $context);

if(empty($content)) {
    echo "there is error";
} else {
    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `FALSE === $content` instead of `empty($content)`?  It could (in theory - I have no idea what the extenral service does) return an emtpy result within the specified timeout, which you might want to handle differently from the error.

Comment: That's up to the OP, I was just demonstrating how to use a context to set a timeout; but I don't know if a timeout would return false from file_get_contents(), certainly not if it would return a strict boolean false

Comment: I admit to not having tried it, but the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for file_get_contents say *"On failure, file_get_contents() will return FALSE."*  I am assuming that a timeout counts as a failure.  As you say, up to the OP if they want to lump an empty response in as a failure or not.

Comment: This code show me some warning Warning: file_get_contents(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330752/i-need-to-run-php-code-within-in-10-second-if-it-run-then-print-content-otherwi) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in C:\wamp\www\tryphp\test.php on line 32

Comment: So what was the URL that you were trying to access?

Comment: and when i am running these code on server then nothing is happening ,means getting blank page

Comment: Can you run file_get_contents() without the context from your server? Or are you always getting an error?

Comment: http://content.webdunia.net/content/content.php?catid=mumweather&langid=hi&mobileno=9826070200&cid=40

Comment: Does file_get_contents() work with the url you've listed here without a context?

Comment: yes but this url not working here and when internal url take more than 10 second for loading then this code gives me error

Answer (score 0):

default_socket_timeout is  the default timeout in ini-setting, which is 60 seconds. you can change it to it like this

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10);
```

Next way to use stream_context_create to set the timeout as HTTP context options of the HTTP stream wrapper in use:

```
$content= stream_context_create(array('http'=>
array(
    'timeout' => 10, //for 10 secs
)
```

));

`echo file_get_contents('http://anyurl/test1.php', false, $content);`